# Update column in database where max value php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got problem here. im updating name where B has the biggest value.

so the results are

```
B  | name
---|------
 1 | 
 2 | 
 3 | YES
```

but when column B changes value the problem is column name with row value 3 still has a value.

```
B  | name
---|------
 1 | 
 4 | YES
 3 | YES
```

the results should be.

```
B  | name
---|------
 1 | 
 4 | YES
 3 |
```

if

```
B  | name
---|------
 0 | 
 0 | 
 0 |
```

then

```
B  | name
---|------
 0 | 
 0 | 
 0 |
```

if,

```
B  | name
---|------
 4 | 
 4 | 
 2 |
```

then

```
B  | name
---|------
 4 | YES
 4 | YES
 2 |
```

this is what i want.

im only using this simple code.

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE products SET name='YES' ORDER BY B DESC";
```

Comment: Maybe just add `WHERE B > 0`  ?

Comment: You need to use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do you need only one `name` to be 'yes' and all the others always be empty?

Comment: i want  place yes on the name which has the highest "B" value.

Comment: Then use `MAX()`. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/ and maybe with `HAVING` and make sure that your numbered column is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update the row in the the table where column B is the highest value? You definitely need a "WHERE" clause, but you also need to know the highest value in that column.  Why don't you query the database first to retrieve the highest value from column B?

```
$maxvalue = "SELECT `B` FROM products ORDER BY `B` DESC LIMIT 1"
```

and then insert into the database WHERE the column B equals this value?

```
"UPDATE products SET name='YES' WHERE B = $maxvalue"
```

This is not complete code, just conceptual. I will clean it up and edit this answer...

Comment: my code is already working
     $sql3 = "UPDATE products SET name='YES' ORDER BY B DESC";

but my problem is that once the value of B changes as shown above, column name with B=3 still has a value of YES.

Answer (score -1):

You have to run `UPDATE products set name = '';` everytime and then :

```
UPDATE products set name = 'YES'
WHERE B > 0
ORDER BY B DESC
```

Comment: `WHERE B > 0` would match 1,2,3,4 etc. OP wants the highest "B" value.

Comment: I tend to think that using `MAX()` or `HAVING` would work better, as per http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/ but that's just me ;-) yet OP's question is a bit unclear whether they want to do all matching, or just one.

Comment: Yes, but this one is a little bit faster than using a subquery

Comment: No argument there ;-)

Comment: all you have to do is before updating any is to set the value (name) to empty, `UPDATE products set name = ''`